# Diactric marks like `ąęłćżńźó` not working with keyboard shortcut

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typesetting, shortcuts, character, type

Is there any possibility to be able to write using `alt + []` to make diactric marks **(Polish)**, while having Adobe Illustrator in English language? Using for example `alt + e` only results in starting export command.

After choosing `Polish` language in `Characters` options, shortcuts still not working.

After choosing `Polish` in `Document setup > Type`, shortcuts still not working.

Note that everything is fine in Photoshop or InDesign or other applications in my OS.

---

My environment:

- OS: Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
- OS Language: English US
- OS Keyboard settings: Polish programmer
- Illustrator Version: 26.5.2

---

*PS. Changing program language is not an option*

Comment: workaround: would it be an option to clear all Illustrator's key combinations that overlap with your intended function? You can access Keyboard Shortcuts in the main Edit menu,

Comment: I tried this method. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: its probably possible to do this by changing how the os keyboard layout works. Because thats how its done in scandic region making some adobe shortcuts impossible since the os overrides the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary workaround I found is using `Shift` + `~` and then press e.g `e`.

Found it [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/unable-to-use-special-characters-while-typing-in-illustrator-alt-gr-issue/m-p/9269580)

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned this for some reason works for you in InDesign, you can type the actual text in InDesign and copy paste back to Illustrator with the proper glyphs in place.

InDesign also keeps track of recently used glyphs, in the Glyphs panel, and that is another way to re-use specific glyphs faster. I have actually used this a few times with eastern-EU languages, you punch in all the glyphs you need, InDesign will build that "Recenlty Used" list, and then you drag this window close to your textbox and click around and replace the glyphs where needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a automation app would be perfect for you, if you have this problem often. I'm working on mac and could recommend Keyboard Maestro as a cheap option for mac.

Anyhow on windows I found a free app that should work for you.
[fastkeysautomation.com](https://fastkeysautomation.com)
<sup>(Untested and not affiliated)</sup>

With apps like this you can set custom shortcuts like:
`Ctrl` `Alt` `Shift` `o` -> ō

Or text expansions like:
`´o` -> ō
`´n` -> ń